# Syntax ambiguities of C++

Tags: c++, parsing, language-lawyer, grammar

Assume there is a declaration:

```
struct A { static int i; };
A a;
```

As I know, the input string `int decltype(a)::i = 0;` has no strictly described behaviour.

It can be parsed as `int        decltype(a)::i       = 0;`, where:
`int` is a *decl-specifier* and `decltype(a)::i` the `declarator`.

However,it can be parsed as `int decltype(a)    ::i = 0;`,where
`int` and `decltype(a)` are parsed as`decl-specifer`s, and `::i` is the (re)declaration of a global variable `i` - the compiler should give a error msg which goes like "a *decl-specifier-seq* should not contain two *type-specifier*s".

I clearly know the first way to parse should be the right one but I can't find any proof.

Anyway, in `int A::a = 0;`, `A` is sure to be parsed as part of `declarator` because `A` is a *type-name* and as described in standard

> If a *type-name* is encountered while parsing a decl-specifier-seq, it is interpreted as part of the *decl-specifier-seq* if and only if there is no previous *type-specifier* other than a *cv-qualifier* in the *decl-specifier-seq*.

In constrant, `decltype(a)` is not a *type-name*, it's a *type-specifier*.

I am not 'finding a quarrel in a straw', I have this question because I'm writing my parser for C++.

So, I wonder if the description should be:

> If a **type-specifier** is encountered while parsing a *decl-specifier-seq*, it is interpreted as part of the *decl-specifier-seq* if and only if there is no previous *type-specifier* other than a *cv-qualifier* in the *decl-specifier-seq*.

Comment: *I have this question because I'm wrote my parser for C++* good luck; given how atrociously bad the C++ grammar is, it looks like a horrible way to spend a Sunday afternoon. If you are actually creating a tool of some sort (and you are not just parsing C++ for an exercise in masochism) you may be interested in `libclang` - let it deal with the grammar madness and do your stuff on a nice AST.

Comment: Build pure C++ grammars is hard enough (stackoverflow.com/a/1004737/120163), partly because any grammar you produce must contain some ambiguous parses. What is harder is finding chapter&verse in the standard for each such ambiguous parse, that resolves its interpretation (partly because even the standard is, uh, ambiguous, in a number of places). Another answer has played language lawyer for you. I think the lesson is you are going to have this problem a lot, and you decide if  you really want this war or you'd rather just pick one of several front ends that already does all this for you.

Answer (score 3):

Your definition is explicitly disallowed by [[dcl.meaning]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.meaning#1):

> The *nested-name-specifier* of a qualified *declarator-id* shall not begin with a *decltype-specifier*.

(GCC and VC++ are buggy in this respect.)

Your implementation's concrete diagnostic (whether referring to multiple *type-specifier*s or an invalid *nested-name-specifier*) is then just a QoI issue. In actuality, implementations will probably implement some variation of the maximum munch principle on *type-specifier*s, similar to what the [original wording of your quote resembled](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#808) (which is why GCC and VC++ accept your code). However, [ICC gives the exact error message](http://goo.gl/a1fZdS) you expected:

> error: invalid combination of type specifiers

Note that your "resolution" is also incorrect, because we can have multiple *type-specifier*s; see [[dcl.type]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type#2). In fact, the wording is fine as is, because if the beginning of a **valid** declarator (in your invalid case, `decltype(a)`) is a *type-specifier*, it also is a *type-name*.

Comment: @ChungkingExpress That rule works and does what it should: Keep valid code valid, and invalid code invalid. If you find a counterexample, we're talkin'.

Comment: This answer suggests to me that `struct S { static int i; }; typedef S T; int T::i;` is supposed to be ill-formed too. Is that a correct interpretation of your answer? If so, does any implementation agree with that interpretation?

Comment: @hvd ... your code is fine, because `T` is a *type-name*, naming `S`, and is not part of the *decl-specifier-seq* because `int` was encountered, which is a *(simple-)type-specifier*. How did you interpret my answer?

Comment: @Columbo `T` is not `S`'s class name. I thought you were focusing on "shall be qualified by its class name" as requiring exactly the class name, nothing equivalent allowed.

Comment: @hvd Nevermind, I found the right quote - looked in the wrong places all along! The quote about class names is probably just defective. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yup, that quote definitely covers it, nice find. I'm not 100% convinced this is the reason it's disallowed, but it doesn't matter much either way.

Comment: @hvd I tracked the change down. It happened via [N3049](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3049.pdf). I contacted the author about the original intent.

Comment: very thankful for your answer, there is also a problem: when parsing:`A :: a....` and the `A` has been parsed as a `type-name` and the next token is `::`, should I assert the `nested-name-specifier`(A::) has been encountered or defer the commitment until found that `a` is a member of `A`?

Comment: @ChungkingExpress I'm not familiar with how compilers would analyze a statement, but you probably have to try to parse the statement as both an expression and a declaration, and see what happens. For e.g. `A::a(I)`, a declaration parser would definitely assume `A` is part of the *decl-specifier-seq*. However, it may then find that the parentheses contain an expression (when `I` is an `int`), not a list of declarators.  The expression parser, on the other hand, would parse `A::a` as a *qualified-id*, then determine the whole thing is a function call. (Just give up already!)

Comment: @hvd Yeah, I was mistaken - the motivation for this was code like [that one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d29bbcf6686b0189).

Comment: @Columbo Nice. Fixing that up a little bit to `template<class T> struct S { S f(); }; template<class T> S<T> decltype(S<T>().f())::f() { }` it gives an internal compiler error with GCC. Probably not worth reporting, I think there's already a bug report about not diagnosing `decltype`, and rejecting it should fix the ICE as well.